# Seeking solution to sync wordpress sites with Server

Tags: multisite, deployment, sync

I am searching for a solution to develop wordpress sites on my local machine via XAMPP and easily sync changes to my webhost. And with changes i mean everything, all files and the database. The only criteria i have that i dont want a subscription model.

I found a couple solutions but these are all monthly or yearly subscriptions. I am absolutely willing to pay money but i want to pay once and thats it ...

Does anybody know any Tools/Software?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should sync your files using ie. SSH or GIT software (see also [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316057/best-way-to-synchronize-local-code-with-server))

Comment: This does not work for wordpress .. I am aware of github but you cant just copy the database from a localhost to a live system since the base url is changing. This is why specifically asked for a solution that works with wordpress.

Comment: You should try ie. SSH for files and DB replication for DB (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)